# $watchCollection always has the same object as new and old value

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am watching an object with $watchCollection. In the callback, I want to know what property of the object got changed, but the issue I have is in the callback both new and old values are same objects. Is there a way for me to watch a object and find which property of the object is changed.

http://jsfiddle.net/SQuVy/325/

```
 angular.module('watchApp', []).controller('watchCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.b = {
        value1: 1,
        value2: 2,    
        value3: 3
     };

    $scope.$watchCollection('b', function(newvalue,oldvalue) {
           console.log(newvalue);// both new and old are same objects
           console.log(oldvalue);
    }, true);
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2621 I'm not an angular developer but cannot you use `$watch` instead? http://jsfiddle.net/SQuVy/333/

Comment: @A.Wolff yes, that is the problem, he dont have a collection here, he has a js object, it is not an array, you have to use `$watch`

Comment: possible duplicate: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2621

Answer (score -1):

Your `$watch` will be fired any time the reference to your `$scope` property is updated.  That doesn't necessarily mean that the object that the reference points to has changed, just the reference itself.

Watching a collection is no different.  To avoid this issue, try the following code:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('b', function(val, prev){
    if(val !== prev){
         // do whatever you need here
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry I forgot you added too `// do whatever you need here`, see the fiddle please, this is not the problem, I didnt downvoted btw